# Is this Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 200 buses in the city. Each bus breaks down with probability 0.005 each day. Assuming that buses break down independently what's the probability of breaking down not more than 3 buses a day?

Any hints ?

**Edit:** Is this true in Poisson Distribution: $EX = p * n = 0,005 * 200 = 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $n=200$ and $p=0.005$. We have to evaluate probability of $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ buses broken down in a day:

$P=(1-p)^{200}+\binom{200}{1}(1-p)^{199}p+\binom{200}{2}(1-p)^{198}p^2+\binom{200}{3}(1-p)^{197}p^3$.

Since $np<10$ and $n\geq 30$, we can estimate the previous by Poisson formula:
$P\{0\leq X \leq 3\}=\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$, where $X$ is number of broken buses and $\lambda=np=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: I have second thoughts. The result i got is $e^{-1}* (2 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!}) = 0,98$ Is this the probability or a value I need to check in the tables?

Comment: That is the probability, if you check it in the table, you will find a more precise result $0,981012$.

Comment: But it doesnt make sens. If I want to check if 5 or more buses break down the value of probability get over $1$ which isn't possible.

Comment: No, for 5 buses I get 0.999406 from the table. When you have binomial distribution as in example $B(200,0.005)$, it is better to estimate it with Poisson distribution and use table.